# How to write BatchProcessor for lambda with Kafka trigger in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, apache-kafka-streams

I have a lambda with Kafka trigger. Lambda takes a batch of Kafka messages. How to return Kafka messages to the Kafka cluster to retry if the processing of message was failed similarly as SQS, DynamoDBStreams, KinesisDataStreams using [aws_lambda_powertools](https://pypi.org/project/aws-lambda-powertools/)?

Does anybody know how to treat successful messages, and "return" failed Kafka messages to the Kafka cluster? Or is it impossible?

In the documentation it is written that **Lambda retries the whole batch of messages**:
[If your function returns an error for any of the messages in a batch, Lambda retries the whole batch of messages until processing succeeds or the messages expire. You can send records that fail all retry attempts to an on-failure destination for later processing.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html)

Then does it lead to the duplication of processing messages? how to handle and ignore already processed messages?